# Append elements to tag in json dictionary using python

Tags: python, json, file, append

How can I append to json file dictionary, a certain value to its specific tag.

```
{"dict": [
    {
     "tag": "adult",
     "name": ["John", "Elle"],
     "age": ["25", "23"],
    },
    {
     "tag": "elderly",
     "name": ["Mary", "Matthew"],
     "age": ["67", "80"],
}
```

Here, after user input their name and age, to find a way to **append** to json file in specific **tag** (eg. A person named "**Stacy**" of age **29**, should be added only to "**adult**"

So the updated should look like so if we add eg. "Stacy" aged "29" to the adult tag:

```
{
     "tag": "adult",
     "name": ["John", "Elle", "Stacy"],
     "age": ["25", "23", "29"],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you made the overall dictionary value into a list rather than keeping it a dictionary. If not, I would suggest something like this:

```
dict = { "adult": { "name": ["John", "Elle"], "age": ["25", "23"] },  "elderly": { "name": ["Mary", "Matthew"], "age": ["67", "80"] }}
```

Now, "adult" and "elderly" are keys to the dictionary where you can access them like this:

```
dict["adult"] = { "name": ["John", "Elle"], "age": ["25", "23"] }
dict["elderly"] = { "name": ["Mary", "Matthew"], "age": ["67", "80"]}
```

And append your example situation like this:

```
dict["adult"]["name"].append("Stacy")
dict["adult"]["age"].append("29")
```

Which results in the overall dict outputting:

```
dict = { "adult": { "name": ["John", "Elle","Stacy"], "age": ["25", "23","29"] },  "elderly": { "name": ["Mary", "Matthew"], "age": ["67", "80"] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you have to iterate over the list of dictionaries that you have stored in the given json dictionary.
If I assume that you have loaded the json in a variable named 'elements_dict', then you have to iterate over elements_dict['dict'] to access the element and do the needful.
As you haven't mentioned the criteria for age to classify someone as adult, I assumed anyone below 50 can be considered as an adult :) and came up with following way ( Just a very simple representation for you, you can improve accordingly)

```
elements_dict = {"dict": [
    {
     "tag": "adult",
     "name": ["John", "Elle"],
     "age": ["25", "23"],
    },
    {
     "tag": "elderly",
     "name": ["Mary", "Matthew"],
     "age": ["67", "80"],
    }]
}

new_name = "Stacy"
new_age = "29"

for people in elements_dict['dict']:
    if people['tag'] == 'adult' and int(new_age) < 50:
        people['name'].append(new_name)
        people['age'].append(new_age)
    elif people['tag'] == 'elderly' and int(new_age) >= 50:
        people['name'].append(new_name)
        people['age'].append(new_age)

print(elements_dict)
```